# Firebase StartAt Query With Deletions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have a query that looks like:

```
orderByChild("updated_at").startAt(mostRecentUpdatedAt + 1)
```

to implement caching without having to download the whole data set every time I connect, is there a way that I can get child remove events if the child is removed without updating the `updated_at` field?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `addChildEventListener` and implement the `public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)` method.

Comment: That would download all the data every time, which defeats the purpose of having a cache.

Comment: You would want a new data set when you change your data set. If you have a cached data set, and remove an item, you would want to update the cache, which this method allows you to do. Caching data allows you to access data that has not changed, not maintain a state through change. Even still, with this method, you could check your current cache, and update it based on the response.

Comment: I already have a system that does all that. I use a single value event listener to get the current state, so I can update my cache. Then I use a child value event listener (with the above query to avoid getting all the values I just read), but I don't get remove events because of the query.

Comment: I would look to adjust it and use the code I referred to update you cache, which will get the remove events. What I am offering is a way for you to update the cache and watch for remove events.

Comment: If I do that I'll be downloading all the data twice every time I start this process. Once for the value event listener, and once for the additional child listener. Sure, it's probably not a lot of data, but it's not my data to waste, and not everyone in the world has a high data cap.

Comment: I'm suggesting you get rid of the single event listener and just use the child listener for everything. There are 5 total methods, `onChildChanged`, `onChildMoved`, `onCancelled`, `onChildAdded`, and `onChildRemoved`. You can use the `addChildEventListener` rather than the single event to track child removal, and updates. This would allow you to refresh your cache, and update on removal.

Comment: Child listeners don't handle removals that occur when the app is not running, hence the single event listener.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I'm pretty sure they do.

Comment: Only sometimes if you have persistence enabled, but it's not 100% reliable.